# Data accumulator collecting monthly expenditure

Tags: c++, beginner, finance

The idea of the program is to serve as a data accumulator collecting monthly expenditure from a user and later display it.

I wanted to implement classes/methods and just basic stuff that I understand to help me get better at writing better C++ programs.

This program works and does what I want it to do, but I figure since this being my "first" program, I'm sure there are bad habits or practices that I'm implementing that I would want to avoid later on. So if anyone can pick the flaws in my code, please feel free to highlight them.

I would like to correct my flaws early on while I can. I'll add that I'm aware that my current design is not meant to store the data once the program quits. I will eventually use GUI design and expand this program to store data permanently, but for now, this what I wrote.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

string concat_date(int m, int d, int y){

string tot_dt,st_m;

if (m == 0) {
string st_temp("January ");
st_m = st_temp;
}
if (m == 1) {
string st_temp("February ");
st_m = st_temp;
}
if (m == 2) {
string st_temp("March ");
st_m = st_temp;
}    if (m == 3) {
string st_temp("April ");
st_m = st_temp;
}    if (m == 4) {
string st_temp("May ");
st_m = st_temp;
}    if (m == 5) {
string st_temp("June ");
st_m = st_temp;
}    if (m == 6) {
string st_temp("July ");
st_m = st_temp;
}    if (m == 7) {
string st_temp("August ");
st_m = st_temp;
}    if (m == 8) {
string st_temp("September ");
st_m = st_temp;
}    if (m == 9) {
string st_temp("October ");
st_m = st_temp;
}    if (m == 10) {
string st_temp("November ");
st_m = st_temp;
}
if (m == 11) {
string st_temp("December ");
st_m = st_temp;
}

string st_d = to_string(d);
string st_y = to_string(y);
tot_dt = st_m + st_d + "," + "'" + st_y[1] + st_y[2];

return  tot_dt;
}

string tot_exp(string md,string cs,string st,string fd,string as){

string intEx;

if (md.length() == 0) {
md = "0";
}
if (cs.length() == 0) {
cs = "0";
}
if (st.length() == 0) {
st = "0";
}
if (fd.length() == 0) {
fd = "0";
}
 if (as.length() == 0) {
as = "0";
}

intEx = "Medical:" + md + "$.\n" + "Cosmetics:" + cs + "$.\n"+ "Stationery:" + st + "$.\n"+ "Food & Drinks:" + fd + "$.\n" + "Assorted:" + as+ "$.\n";
return intEx;
}

string datedisplay(string dd){

string id;

id = dd;

if (id.length() ) {

}

return id;
}

class user_data{

public:
string first_name;
string last_name;
string date;
string expn;

user_data(string fn, string ln, string dt, string ex){
first_name = fn;
last_name = ln;
date = dt;
expn = ex;
}
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

// Declare a list
list<user_data> FP;
list<user_data>::iterator iter;

string fn, ln, dt;

int m,d,y;
// Medical, Cosmetics, Stationery, Food & drinks, Assorted    expenditure
string md, cs, st, fd, as, TotEx;

while (true) {
string yn;
cout << "Would you like to add a name to the register or    quit(Press 0 to exit or Y/y to continue)?";
getline(cin, yn);

if (yn == "0") {
    break;
}

// *****************************************
// Collects User data.
// *****************************************
cout << "Enter your first name:";
getline(cin,fn);
cout << "Enter your last name:";
getline(cin,ln);

// *****************************************
// gets the date/month/year info from system.
// *****************************************

time_t t = time(NULL);
tm *tm_pointer = localtime(&t);
m = tm_pointer -> tm_mon;
d = tm_pointer -> tm_mday;
y = tm_pointer -> tm_year;

dt = concat_date(m, d, y);
// *****************************************

// *****************************************
// collects the user expenditure info
// *****************************************
cout << "How much money did you spend today?. Specify (in  Dollars) against each category."<<endl;
cout << "Medical = " ;
getline(cin, md);
cout << "Cosmetics = " ;
getline(cin, cs);
cout << "Stationery = " ;
getline(cin, st);
cout << "Food & Drinks = " ;
getline(cin, fd);
cout << "Assorted = " ;
getline(cin, as);

// *****************************************
// Arrange the expenses info in the lists.
// *****************************************
TotEx = tot_exp(md,cs,st,fd,as);
user_data udone(fn,ln,dt,TotEx);
FP.push_back(udone);
}

// *****************************************
//  Display all the expenses info
// *****************************************
for (iter = FP.begin(); iter != FP.end(); iter++) {
cout << iter->last_name << ", " << iter->first_name << endl;
cout << "Expenditure for "<< iter->date << " is \n" << iter->expn  << endl << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

**Note**: I made the mistake of posting it on another Stack Exchange site for which I was promptly pointed to this section, so I'd like to add the few things that were pointed out on that page before I moved my question here:

1. I would told to avoid `using namespace std`. I was shown the reason as well. I understand, I'll learn to fix that.
2. I was told to better explain my program. I understand the need for better comprehension, but at one point the name of my 'list' which I have called "FP" was questioned. Incidentally, I meant FP as an abbreviation for a Finance Planner. But overlooking that connection, is it essential to have "more understandable" variables as well. I don't see the need to have variables that might be "very understandable" if my program is explained well in detail.

Comment: Please put what the code does in the title. Everyone who posts a question here wants their code nitpicked.

Comment: Does this code's indentation match your code's actual indentation?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Edward Fair enough. I understand why, but when I tried to post the edited code as part of my comment, it said I was over the allowed limit. Hence i edited the original. As a side note, i'm more than impressed with the options/design available on both stack overflow and code review in terms of what one can do. Not many forums would let another user roll back the original code although I made the change. Just highlights the fact that I have a long way to go to when I won't be that impressed by such trivial factors.

Comment: Oh I don't know, I've been here for sometime and the way the CodeReview works still impresses me! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` within your program is generally [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Fix your formatting

There are inconsistent spaces at the beginning of lines, inconsistent indentation and inconsistent use and placement of curly braces `{}`.  Being consistent helps others read and understand your code.

### Eliminate unused variables

Unused variables are a sign of poor code quality, so eliminating them should be a priority.  In this code, `main` uses neither `argc` nor `argv` and so that function should be `int main()`.

### Eliminate unused routine

The code defines a peculiarly useless function `datedisplay` but it is not actually used and can be eliminated from the code.  Smaller code typically runs faster, so there's a small chance that this could improve speed as well.

### Think of the user

The program issues a prompt "... quit(Press 0 to exit or Y/y to continue)?" but a response of "N" also continues.  This is annoying at best.  Better would to make the choices similar, such as 0 or 1 or Y or N.

### Consider using range-for syntax

The code currently prints the resulting `list` with this code:

```
for (iter = FP.begin(); iter != FP.end(); iter++) {
    std::cout << iter->last_name << ", " << iter->first_name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Expenditure for "<< iter->date << " is \n" << iter->expn  << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

This could be written much more simply with a range-for:

```
for (const auto &item : FP) {
    std::cout << item.last_name << ", " << item.first_name 
        << "\nExpenditure for "<< item.date << " is \n" 
        << item.expn  << "\n\n";
}
```

### Declare variables as late as possible

Rather than using the old C-style of declaring all variables at the top of a function, use the modern C++-style and declare variables as late as possible.  Doing so can sometimes help the compiler figure out register allocation, resulting in faster, smaller code.

### Use the appropriate types

Is an expense really best represented as a `std::string`?  Right now, one can answer all of the questions with text.  Leading to an output like this:

```
> Transistor, Edward
> Expenditure for December 6,'16 is 
> Medical:two chickens$.
> Cosmetics:one pig$.
> Stationery:nothing at all$.
> Food & Drinks:more than I should have$.
> Assorted:pocket change$.
```

Also, a `std::vector` is likely to be a much more appropriate data structure than `std::list` for this program.

### Make data members private

The `user_data` class has all of its members `public` which is probably a sign that the class design is not very good.  Instead, add member functions to the class so that internal access is not required.

### Improve your constructor

The `user_data` class has four data elements; `first_name`, `last_name`, `date` and `expn`.  The constructor should create and initialize those four things. A more modern style for your constructor might be this:

```
user_data(std::string fn, std::string ln, std::string dt, std::string ex) :
    first_name{fn},
    last_name{ln},
    date{dt},
    expn{ex}
{ }
```

### Make better use of objects

The `user_data` class, in addition to be rather poorly named, is not really doing much in this code.  First, using the right kind of data items (as mentioned above) would help.  Second, write some `friend` functions to handle input and output.  For example:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const user_data &ud) {
    return out << ud.last_name << ", " << ud.first_name 
        << "\nExpenditure for "<< ud.date << " is \n" 
        << ud.expn;
}
```

My quick rewrite of your `user_data` class looks like this:

```
class user_data{
private:
    static constexpr size_t expense_count{5};
    static const std::array<std::string, expense_count> labels;

    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    std::tm date;
    std::array<int, expense_count> expn;

public:
    user_data();

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, user_data &ud);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const user_data &ud);
};

const std::array<std::string, user_data::expense_count> user_data::labels {
    "Medical", "Cosmetics", "Stationery", "Food & Drinks", "Assorted"
};
```

With it, `main` looks like this:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<user_data> FP;

    while (addmore()) {
        user_data udone;
        std::cin >> udone;
        FP.push_back(udone);
    }
    for (const auto &item : FP) {
        std::cout << item << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

### Consider expandability

Are the particular expense classes going to be the ones that will always be used?  Maybe not.  Also, it would make sense to encapsulate the name and the amout in a single object.  I'd suggest making the `expn` member of `user_data` a `std::array` or `std::vector` of integers instead, and have the names supplied via the output inserter functon (a modification of the one just above would work.)

### Don't make pointless copies of variables

The code currently contains these lines:

```
m = tm_pointer -> tm_mon;
d = tm_pointer -> tm_mday;
y = tm_pointer -> tm_year;

dt = concat_date(m, d, y);
```

However, there's no real point to making those copies.  It could instead have been written like this:

```
dt = concat_date(tm_pointer->tm_mon, tm_pointer->tm_mday, tm_pointer->tm_year);
```

### Use library functions

One of the things the code does is to create a date string in a specialized format in `concat_date`. However, this could be done more easily by using `std::strftime`.

### Don't use std::endl unless you really need to flush the stream

The difference between `std::endl` and `'\n'` is that `std::endl` actually flushes the stream. This can be a costly operation in terms of processing time, so it's best to get in the habit of only using it when flushing the stream is actually required. It's not for this code.

### Omit `return 0`

When a C or C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no need to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

**Note:** when I make this suggestion, it's almost invariably followed by one of two kinds of comments:  "I didn't know that." or "That's bad advice!"  My rationale is that it's safe and useful to rely on compiler behavior explicitly supported by the standard.  For C, since C99; see ISO/IEC 9899:1999 section 5.1.2.2.3:

> [...] a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.

For C++, since the first standard in 1998; see ISO/IEC 14882:1998 section 3.6.1:

> If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;

All versions of both standards since then (C99 and C++98) have maintained the same idea.  We rely on automatically generated member functions in C++, and few people write explicit `return;` statements at the end of a `void` function.  Reasons against omitting seem to boil down to ["it looks weird"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581993/what-the-reasons-for-against-returning-0-from-main-in-iso-c/2582015#2582015).  If, like me, you're curious about the rationale for the change to the C standard [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394171/what-was-the-rationale-for-making-return-0-at-the-end-of-main-optional).  Also note that in the early 1990s this was considered "sloppy practice" because it was undefined behavior (although widely supported) at the time.

So I advocate omitting it; others disagree (often vehemently!)  In any case, if you encounter code that omits it, you'll know that it's explicitly supported by the standard and you'll know what it means.

### A worked example

Here's how it looked when I applied most of these suggestions to your code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

class PersonalExpenses{
private:
    static constexpr size_t expense_count{5};
    static const std::array<std::string, expense_count> labels;

    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    std::tm date;
    std::array<int, expense_count> expn;

public:
    PersonalExpenses();

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, PersonalExpenses &ud);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const PersonalExpenses &ud);
};

const std::array<std::string, PersonalExpenses::expense_count> PersonalExpenses::labels {
    "Medical", "Cosmetics", "Stationery", "Food & Drinks", "Assorted"
};

PersonalExpenses::PersonalExpenses() {
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    date = *localtime(&t);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const PersonalExpenses &ud) {
    out << ud.last_name << ", " << ud.first_name 
        << "\nExpenditure for "
        << std::put_time(&ud.date, "%B %e,`%y") 
        << " is \n";
    for (size_t i=0; i < PersonalExpenses::expense_count; ++i ) {
        out << ud.labels[i] << ":" << ud.expn[i] << "$.\n";
    }
    return out;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, PersonalExpenses &ud) {
    std::string val;
    std::cout << "Enter your first name:";
    std::getline(std::cin,ud.first_name);
    std::cout << "Enter your last name:";
    std::getline(std::cin,ud.last_name);

    std::cout << "How much money did you spend today?. Specify (in  Dollars) against each category."<<std::endl;
    for (size_t i=0; i < PersonalExpenses::expense_count; ++i) {
        std::cout << ud.labels[i] << " = " ;
        std::getline(std::cin, val);
        ud.expn[i] = std::stoi(val);
    }
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    ud.date = *std::localtime(&t);
    return in;
}

bool addmore() {
    std::string yn;
    std::cout << "Would you like to add a name to the register or    quit(Press 0 to exit or Y/y to continue)?";
    std::getline(std::cin, yn);
    return yn != "0";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<PersonalExpenses> ledger;

    while (addmore()) {
        PersonalExpenses udone;
        std::cin >> udone;
        ledger.push_back(udone);
    }
    for (const auto &item : ledger) {
        std::cout << item << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I really do appreciate your feedback. I never understood why people insisted on typing "std" till I was shown the reason yesterday. its going to be a habit I'll have to get used to. 
As for the private data members, I'm still trying to make that distinction between what I need to keep private and what I need to make public. it will take me a while, but I'll get there. 
  As with the other things that you mentioned as well, I'll spend a while to make these a habit . Thank you :)

Comment: Based on your suggestion, i got till "Make better use of objects" where I got stuck. I edited  the code in the original post to replicate what I have modified so far. I have also marked the section where I have an error. When I defined the labels, the error I get is " Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::array<std::__1::basic_string<char>, 5>'" . 
  I searched on google and found instances where people have reported similar problems. 
  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797051/implicit-instantiation-of-undefined-template-when-forward-declaring-template-c )

Comment: Therefore what I did was try to re-arrange the code to move the definition of the template ahead of its use, but that leaves me with the problem that the class is undefined at that stage. So I'm stuck there. How could I overcome this ?

Comment: Instead of editing the question, you should post a new follow up question because such an edit invalidates the answers. See http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765

Comment: The answer to your immediate problem is that you need to `#include <array>`

Comment: I played around with codes based on what you suggested. I was able to add a "setname" member function within the user_data class that allowed me to add the first name & last name as part of the class rather than the previous design. But I couldn't get to add the 'date' and ''expn" as part of the member function & cin . Could you help me out please? FYI, I tried adding what I have done so far  in this comment, but apparently that exceeds the allowed limit of characters.

Comment: I added a fully worked example to illustrate.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I'm figuring out your code and hopefully i'll be a better coder for it. Thank you, but I want you to know it is people like you that set me a target to emulate. I hope to be a better programmer than you some day :) you'd probably get better with time and i'd take ages to get there, but thank you for being a source of motivation to help me along.

Comment: I'm sure you'll be a better programmer than me at some point, and that you'll help others as you've been helped.  That's why we're all here!

Comment: I wanted to write the struct data to a text file. So I can later add features such as to calculate mean/highest/lowest expenditure and so on from the stored data. Therefore, I added these lines to the existing code within the ostream << operator. (contd ... )

Comment: std::ofstream data_file("Expenditure_data.txt", std::fstream::app);
    
    if (data_file.good()) {
        data_file << "\n" << ud.first_name << "\n";
        data_file << ud.last_name << "\n";
        data_file << std::put_time(&ud.date, "%B %e,`%y") << "\n";
        data_file << ud.labels[0] << ":" << ud.expn[0] << "$.\n";
        data_file << ud.labels[1] << ":" << ud.expn[1] << "$.\n";
        data_file << ud.labels[2] << ":" << ud.expn[2] << "$.\n";
    }
    data_file.close();

Comment: I couldn't add the additional code here and make it look like a code. it looks messy in the previous comment.  so I added it to the "worked example" below the main function. But in "my code", it is actually placed within the  ostream operator << . The question I have is, 
1. Is this the best way to write/store data or is there a better way ?
2. Could you also let me know how I could 'clear' all data within the text file if necessary and start with a blank text file.

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple things that Edward did not mention. Keep in mind that this is one of your first C++ programs, so it's a good time to form good habits if your goal is to make professional code and your program is very simple so there's no reason it shouldn't be perfectly understood in these areas:

### Use good variable names

You questioned in your post whether having "more understandable" variables is important. A couple considerations in response:

1. **Variables have meaningful names to be understood by humans.** A machine could easily understand if you named your variables `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, etc. but you give them meaningful names in order to remember them. `st_m` is understood by you as "string month" likely.
2. **Your code isn't just used by you,** at least not when you're working in a real company. Even if you might be the only coder in the team, or company, eventually someone will replace you and inherit your code. In light of this, your code needs to be understood by others.
3. **You won't remember everything.** I bet you when you go work on another program and come back to this you'll have to spend time remembering what your variables were doing exactly. It's much easier if variables have meaningful names.
4. **Typing more is a low cost compared to hours debugging.** It could be really terrible if you mistakenly mixed up variables in *some random line of code* and couldn't find it. When you start using an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) such as Visual Studio, they give you autocomplete and long names such as `DoThisSuperAwesomeFunctionWithoutFail()` are much less daunting.

Some of this might not be relevant now, but it's important to form good habits. Some of this taken from [A Guide to Naming Variables](https://a-nickels-worth.blogspot.com/2016/04/a-guide-to-naming-variables.html) (might be beyond you right now).

### Use constants

When I was learning programming we called code that should be replaced with constants "magic numbers" because they seemingly appear out of thin air—unexplained. For instance 3.14 is a constant for the value of pi, and if you were to use pi in your code, you shouldn't write 3.14 everywhere; you should just set one const variable somewhere and use that all over your code.

Use of constants is for:

- **Understandability.** Names mean more than literals. It's easier to understand you're doing the formula for the circumference of a circle if it's `2 * pi * r` rather than `2 * 3.14 * r`.
- **Guarding against errors.** What if you accidentally wrote 3.15 somewhere instead of 3.14? With one constant you can at least know the value is the same everywhere.
- **Making it easy to make changes later** across your entire program. Say, you wanted the value of pi to be more precise: 3.14159. You only have to make the change in one place!

Constants generally have all-caps names. An example for your code:

```
// 0 based indexing for months
const int MONTH_JANUARY = 0;
const int MONTH_FEBRUARY = 1;
const int MONTH_MARCH = 2;
...

const std::string JANUARY = "January ";
const std::string FEBRUARY = "FEBRUARY ";
const std::string MARCH = "MARCH ";
...

string concat_date(int m, int d, int y)
{
    string tot_dt, st_m;

    if (m == MONTH_JANUARY)
    {
        st_m = JANUARY;
    }
    if (m == MONTH_FEBRUARY)
    {
        st_m = FEBRUARY;
    }
    if (m == MONTH_MARCH)
    {
        st_m = MARCH;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. I see your point about using constants. Time for an admission. Due to necessity at work, i actually wrote assembly language codes for semiconductor chips. Without any background in C/C++ programming, I got by for 5 years writing assembly language codes. I learnt things the hard way making mistakes about NOT using constants. So i see your point. Which just shows I have no excuse to be making these mistakes just because I'm using a different language.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: 5 years in assembly is impressive! But it is good that we have some good compilers to do the difficult work for us.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this useful (rather than purely a programming exercise), I think you'd probably be (much) better off changing its basic nature.

Right now, I see a few basic problems. First of all, the names of the categories are fixed. Some may not apply in some situations. Some may be far too coarse in others.

Second, the basic idea of it is that it works only in a single batch. That is, I need to enter all the data at once, and then it spits out an answer. The next time, I have to start over from the beginning.

Third, the sequence is fixed, so if I have 10 items in one category, and none in any of the others, I need to enter `0` into each of the other 4 categories 10 times over just to enter my 10 items.

To make the program more useful, I'd at least consider having it take its input from a file, formatted something like this:

```
cosmetics: 10
stationery: 5
food and drinks: 7
stationery: 7
```

This allows the user to enter exactly the data they care about. It lets them enter data as it happens, then run the program to get totals at (for example) the end of the month or end of quarter (or whatever). The input they used is in a file, so it's saved for records. It's also fairly easy to write the code to allow arbitrary categories, so (for example) an automotive maintenance shop might use "spark plugs", "air cleaners", and "oil changes".

Code for this could look something like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

std::ostream &current_date(std::ostream &os) {
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    tm now = *localtime(&t);
    return os << std::put_time(&now, "%d %B '%y");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "usage: totals <filename>\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::string category;
    double value;

    std::map<std::string, double> expenses;

    std::ifstream in(argv[1]);

    while (std::getline(in, category, ':')) {
        std::string temp;
        std::getline(in, temp);

        value = std::stod(temp);

        expenses[category] += value;
    }

    std::cout << "Expenditures for " << current_date << ":\n";
    for (auto e : expenses) {
        std::cout << e.first << " $" << e.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This might sound more like an excuse, but I did think about the point you are making. I figured the user would find it easier to type a 0 for a category he/she is not interested in rather than enter the name of the specific category he/she would like to access. Eventually I'll be using a GUI, so I figured this won't be a problem later on. But I do see the need in my program to structure it better , so adding a new category later on is easier. I'll work on it. Thank you .